# float point multiplication: LOSING speed with AVX against SSE?

Tags: c++, performance, sse, avx

I have code that does the same thing, but the AVX version is considerably SLOWER than the SSE version. Can someone explain that?

What I already did is that I tried to profile the code using VerySleepy, but this was not able to give me any helpful results, it merely confirmed that it's slower...

I already reviewed the commands in an SSE/AVX guide and on my CPU (Haswell) they need the same Latency/Throughput, just the horizontal add needs additional commands for AVX...

** latencies and throughputs **

```
_mm_mul_ps            -> L 5, T 0.5
_mm256_mul_ps         -> L 5, T 0.5
_mm_hadd_ps           -> L 5, T 2
_mm256_hadd_ps        -> L 5, T ?
_mm256_extractf128_ps -> L 1, T 1
```

**Summary of what the code does:**
Final1 = SUM( m_Array1 * m_Array1 * m_Array3 * m_Array3 )

Final2 = SUM( m_Array2 * m_Array2 * m_Array3 * m_Array3 )

Final3 = SUM( m_Array1 * m_Array2 * m_Array3 * m_Array3 )

**init**

```
float Final1 = 0.0f;
float Final2 = 0.0f;
float Final3 = 0.0f;

float* m_Array1 = (float*)_mm_malloc( 32 * sizeof( float ), 32 );
float* m_Array2 = (float*)_mm_malloc( 32 * sizeof( float ), 32 );
float* m_Array3 = (float*)_mm_malloc( 32 * sizeof( float ), 32 );
```

**SSE:**

```
for ( int k = 0; k < 32; k += 4 )
{

    __m128 g1 = _mm_load_ps( m_Array1 + k );
    __m128 g2 = _mm_load_ps( m_Array2 + k );
    __m128 g3 = _mm_load_ps( m_Array3 + k );

    __m128 g1g3 = _mm_mul_ps( g1, g3 );
    __m128 g2g3 = _mm_mul_ps( g2, g3 );

    __m128 a1 = _mm_mul_ps( g1g3, g1g3 );
    __m128 a2 = _mm_mul_ps( g2g3, g2g3 );
    __m128 a3 = _mm_mul_ps( g1g3, g2g3 );

    // horizontal add
    {
        a1 = _mm_hadd_ps( a1, a1 );
        a1 = _mm_hadd_ps( a1, a1 );
        Final1 += _mm_cvtss_f32( a1 );

        a2 = _mm_hadd_ps( a2, a2 );
        a2 = _mm_hadd_ps( a2, a2 );
        Final2 += _mm_cvtss_f32( a2 );

        a3 = _mm_hadd_ps( a3, a3 );
        a3 = _mm_hadd_ps( a3, a3 );
        Final3 += _mm_cvtss_f32( a3 );

    }

}
```

**AVX:**

```
for ( int k = 0; k < 32; k += 8 )
{
    __m256 g1 = _mm256_load_ps( m_Array1 + k );
    __m256 g2 = _mm256_load_ps( m_Array2 + k );
    __m256 g3 = _mm256_load_ps( m_Array3 + k );

    __m256 g1g3 = _mm256_mul_ps( g1, g3 );
    __m256 g2g3 = _mm256_mul_ps( g2, g3 );

    __m256 a1 = _mm256_mul_ps( g1g3, g1g3 );
    __m256 a2 = _mm256_mul_ps( g2g3, g2g3 );
    __m256 a3 = _mm256_mul_ps( g1g3, g2g3 );

    // horizontal add1
    {
        __m256 t1 = _mm256_hadd_ps( a1, a1 );
        __m256 t2 = _mm256_hadd_ps( t1, t1 );
        __m128 t3 = _mm256_extractf128_ps( t2, 1 );
        __m128 t4 = _mm_add_ss( _mm256_castps256_ps128( t2 ), t3 );
        Final1 += _mm_cvtss_f32( t4 );
    }
    // horizontal add2
    {
        __m256 t1 = _mm256_hadd_ps( a2, a2 );
        __m256 t2 = _mm256_hadd_ps( t1, t1 );
        __m128 t3 = _mm256_extractf128_ps( t2, 1 );
        __m128 t4 = _mm_add_ss( _mm256_castps256_ps128( t2 ), t3 );
        Final2 += _mm_cvtss_f32( t4 );
    }
    // horizontal add3
    {
        __m256 t1 = _mm256_hadd_ps( a3, a3 );
        __m256 t2 = _mm256_hadd_ps( t1, t1 );
        __m128 t3 = _mm256_extractf128_ps( t2, 1 );
        __m128 t4 = _mm_add_ss( _mm256_castps256_ps128( t2 ), t3 );
        Final3 += _mm_cvtss_f32( t4 );
    }

}
```

Comment: You need a *much* bigger loop to reliably benchmark these two code fragments. Also the horizontal adds and final scalar value extraction should be outside the loop in both cases.

Comment: It's just a minimal example. Replace the 32's by "some-integer-times-eight", the problem remains the same

Comment: `extractf128ps` is, like all "cross slice" operations, fairly slow. Actually hadd is also fairly slow, but that's in both the AVX and the SSE versions

Comment: AVX has much higher throughput than SSE, but it comes at a higher latency. Sustained workloads hide the latency, short loads expose it

Comment: @PaulR The scalar extraction is done in both cases. even if I take the scalar extraction out, it won't make a difference for AVX vs SSE

Comment: @ddriver: I'll wirte the throughputs/delays in the text above, they are mostly identical

Comment: @S.H: sure, but your code is very inefficient in both cases - if you move the horizontal adds and scalar extraction out of the loop and just use normal (vertical) adds within the loop then you'll get more efficient code in both cases and the relative performance may also change due to the different instruction mix.

Comment: Why do you even do it this way though? You can easily do it almost completely vertically, only summing horizontally once after the loop

Comment: @PaulR: The problem is to multiply the arrays element-wise (as described above) and the summing all the products. I don't see how the summing can be taken out of the loop without storing the multiplications in some other array... Are you sure that your suggestions are in accordance with my "what the code does" section?

Comment: TRying to get back on topic: The operations are almost identical, where does the delay come from??

Comment: `VEXTRACTF128` actually has a latency of 3, not 1

Comment: @S.H: since you're just summing all the products you can just do a vertical add within the loop, giving four partial sums, then do a single horizontal add after the loop to combine these four partial sums. This will be much more efficient and avoids the aforementioned high latency instructions.

Comment: FWIW running your code here on a Haswell, compiling with `clang -O3 -mavx2` gives faster performance with AVX relative to SSE as expected. I suspect either your compiler or benchmarking methods are at fault.

Comment: @PaulR how much of a speedup did you observe?

Comment: @S.H: 1.4x for the original versions, 1.8x for the optimised versions with horizontal adds moved out of the loop.

Comment: Are you making any standard library calls before your AVX code? For example from `math.h`? Try adding `_mm256_zeroupper()` before your AVX code.

Answer (score 5):

I took your code and put it in a test harness, compiled it `clang -O3` and timed it. I also implemented faster versions of the two routines, with the horizontal add moved out of the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>   // gettimeofday
#include <immintrin.h>

static void sse(const float *m_Array1, const float *m_Array2, const float *m_Array3, size_t n, float *Final1, float *Final2, float *Final3)
{
    *Final1 = *Final2 = *Final3 = 0.0f;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k += 4)
    {
        __m128 g1 = _mm_load_ps( m_Array1 + k );
        __m128 g2 = _mm_load_ps( m_Array2 + k );
        __m128 g3 = _mm_load_ps( m_Array3 + k );

        __m128 g1g3 = _mm_mul_ps( g1, g3 );
        __m128 g2g3 = _mm_mul_ps( g2, g3 );

        __m128 a1 = _mm_mul_ps( g1g3, g1g3 );
        __m128 a2 = _mm_mul_ps( g2g3, g2g3 );
        __m128 a3 = _mm_mul_ps( g1g3, g2g3 );

        // horizontal add
        {
            a1 = _mm_hadd_ps( a1, a1 );
            a1 = _mm_hadd_ps( a1, a1 );
            *Final1 += _mm_cvtss_f32( a1 );

            a2 = _mm_hadd_ps( a2, a2 );
            a2 = _mm_hadd_ps( a2, a2 );
            *Final2 += _mm_cvtss_f32( a2 );

            a3 = _mm_hadd_ps( a3, a3 );
            a3 = _mm_hadd_ps( a3, a3 );
            *Final3 += _mm_cvtss_f32( a3 );
        }
    }
}

static void sse_fast(const float *m_Array1, const float *m_Array2, const float *m_Array3, size_t n, float *Final1, float *Final2, float *Final3)
{
    *Final1 = *Final2 = *Final3 = 0.0f;
    __m128 a1 = _mm_setzero_ps();
    __m128 a2 = _mm_setzero_ps();
    __m128 a3 = _mm_setzero_ps();
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k += 4)
    {
        __m128 g1 = _mm_load_ps( m_Array1 + k );
        __m128 g2 = _mm_load_ps( m_Array2 + k );
        __m128 g3 = _mm_load_ps( m_Array3 + k );

        __m128 g1g3 = _mm_mul_ps( g1, g3 );
        __m128 g2g3 = _mm_mul_ps( g2, g3 );

        a1 = _mm_add_ps(a1, _mm_mul_ps( g1g3, g1g3 ));
        a2 = _mm_add_ps(a2, _mm_mul_ps( g2g3, g2g3 ));
        a3 = _mm_add_ps(a3, _mm_mul_ps( g1g3, g2g3 ));
    }
    // horizontal add
    a1 = _mm_hadd_ps( a1, a1 );
    a1 = _mm_hadd_ps( a1, a1 );
    *Final1 += _mm_cvtss_f32( a1 );

    a2 = _mm_hadd_ps( a2, a2 );
    a2 = _mm_hadd_ps( a2, a2 );
    *Final2 += _mm_cvtss_f32( a2 );

    a3 = _mm_hadd_ps( a3, a3 );
    a3 = _mm_hadd_ps( a3, a3 );
    *Final3 += _mm_cvtss_f32( a3 );
}

static void avx(const float *m_Array1, const float *m_Array2, const float *m_Array3, size_t n, float *Final1, float *Final2, float *Final3)
{
    *Final1 = *Final2 = *Final3 = 0.0f;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k += 8 )
    {
        __m256 g1 = _mm256_load_ps( m_Array1 + k );
        __m256 g2 = _mm256_load_ps( m_Array2 + k );
        __m256 g3 = _mm256_load_ps( m_Array3 + k );

        __m256 g1g3 = _mm256_mul_ps( g1, g3 );
        __m256 g2g3 = _mm256_mul_ps( g2, g3 );

        __m256 a1 = _mm256_mul_ps( g1g3, g1g3 );
        __m256 a2 = _mm256_mul_ps( g2g3, g2g3 );
        __m256 a3 = _mm256_mul_ps( g1g3, g2g3 );

        // horizontal add1
        {
            __m256 t1 = _mm256_hadd_ps( a1, a1 );
            __m256 t2 = _mm256_hadd_ps( t1, t1 );
            __m128 t3 = _mm256_extractf128_ps( t2, 1 );
            __m128 t4 = _mm_add_ss( _mm256_castps256_ps128( t2 ), t3 );
            *Final1 += _mm_cvtss_f32( t4 );
        }
        // horizontal add2
        {
            __m256 t1 = _mm256_hadd_ps( a2, a2 );
            __m256 t2 = _mm256_hadd_ps( t1, t1 );
            __m128 t3 = _mm256_extractf128_ps( t2, 1 );
            __m128 t4 = _mm_add_ss( _mm256_castps256_ps128( t2 ), t3 );
            *Final2 += _mm_cvtss_f32( t4 );
        }
        // horizontal add3
        {
            __m256 t1 = _mm256_hadd_ps( a3, a3 );
            __m256 t2 = _mm256_hadd_ps( t1, t1 );
            __m128 t3 = _mm256_extractf128_ps( t2, 1 );
            __m128 t4 = _mm_add_ss( _mm256_castps256_ps128( t2 ), t3 );
            *Final3 += _mm_cvtss_f32( t4 );
        }
    }
}

static void avx_fast(const float *m_Array1, const float *m_Array2, const float *m_Array3, size_t n, float *Final1, float *Final2, float *Final3)
{
    *Final1 = *Final2 = *Final3 = 0.0f;
    __m256 a1 = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    __m256 a2 = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    __m256 a3 = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k += 8 )
    {
        __m256 g1 = _mm256_load_ps( m_Array1 + k );
        __m256 g2 = _mm256_load_ps( m_Array2 + k );
        __m256 g3 = _mm256_load_ps( m_Array3 + k );

        __m256 g1g3 = _mm256_mul_ps( g1, g3 );
        __m256 g2g3 = _mm256_mul_ps( g2, g3 );

        a1 = _mm256_add_ps(a1, _mm256_mul_ps( g1g3, g1g3 ));
        a2 = _mm256_add_ps(a2, _mm256_mul_ps( g2g3, g2g3 ));
        a3 = _mm256_add_ps(a3, _mm256_mul_ps( g1g3, g2g3 ));
    }

    // horizontal add1

    {
        __m256 t1 = _mm256_hadd_ps( a1, a1 );
        __m256 t2 = _mm256_hadd_ps( t1, t1 );
        __m128 t3 = _mm256_extractf128_ps( t2, 1 );
        __m128 t4 = _mm_add_ss( _mm256_castps256_ps128( t2 ), t3 );
        *Final1 += _mm_cvtss_f32( t4 );
    }

    // horizontal add2

    {
        __m256 t1 = _mm256_hadd_ps( a2, a2 );
        __m256 t2 = _mm256_hadd_ps( t1, t1 );
        __m128 t3 = _mm256_extractf128_ps( t2, 1 );
        __m128 t4 = _mm_add_ss( _mm256_castps256_ps128( t2 ), t3 );
        *Final2 += _mm_cvtss_f32( t4 );
    }

    // horizontal add3

    {
        __m256 t1 = _mm256_hadd_ps( a3, a3 );
        __m256 t2 = _mm256_hadd_ps( t1, t1 );
        __m128 t3 = _mm256_extractf128_ps( t2, 1 );
        __m128 t4 = _mm_add_ss( _mm256_castps256_ps128( t2 ), t3 );
        *Final3 += _mm_cvtss_f32( t4 );
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t n = 4096;

    if (argc > 1) n = atoi(argv[1]);

    float *in_1 = valloc(n * sizeof(in_1[0]));
    float *in_2 = valloc(n * sizeof(in_2[0]));
    float *in_3 = valloc(n * sizeof(in_3[0]));
    float out_1, out_2, out_3;

    struct timeval t0, t1;
    double t_ms;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        in_1[i] = (float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX / 2);
        in_2[i] = (float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX / 2);
        in_3[i] = (float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX / 2);
    }

    sse(in_1, in_2, in_3, n, &out_1, &out_2, &out_3);
    printf("sse     : %g, %g, %g\n", out_1, out_2, out_3);
    sse_fast(in_1, in_2, in_3, n, &out_1, &out_2, &out_3);
    printf("sse_fast: %g, %g, %g\n", out_1, out_2, out_3);
    avx(in_1, in_2, in_3, n, &out_1, &out_2, &out_3);
    printf("avx     : %g, %g, %g\n", out_1, out_2, out_3);
    avx_fast(in_1, in_2, in_3, n, &out_1, &out_2, &out_3);
    printf("avx_fast: %g, %g, %g\n", out_1, out_2, out_3);

    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) sse(in_1, in_2, in_3, n, &out_1, &out_2, &out_3);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    t_ms = ((double)(t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) + (double)(t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) * 1.0e-6) * 1.0e3;
    printf("sse     : %g, %g, %g, %g ms\n", out_1, out_2, out_3, t_ms);

    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) sse_fast(in_1, in_2, in_3, n, &out_1, &out_2, &out_3);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    t_ms = ((double)(t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) + (double)(t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) * 1.0e-6) * 1.0e3;
    printf("sse_fast: %g, %g, %g, %g ms\n", out_1, out_2, out_3, t_ms);

    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) avx(in_1, in_2, in_3, n, &out_1, &out_2, &out_3);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    t_ms = ((double)(t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) + (double)(t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) * 1.0e-6) * 1.0e3;
    printf("avx     : %g, %g, %g, %g ms\n", out_1, out_2, out_3, t_ms);

    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) avx_fast(in_1, in_2, in_3, n, &out_1, &out_2, &out_3);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    t_ms = ((double)(t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) + (double)(t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) * 1.0e-6) * 1.0e3;
    printf("avx_fast: %g, %g, %g, %g ms\n", out_1, out_2, out_3, t_ms);

    return 0;
}
```

Results on my 2.6 GHz Haswell (MacBook Pro) were:

```
sse     : 0.439 ms
sse_fast: 0.153 ms
avx     : 0.309 ms
avx_fast: 0.085 ms
```

So the AVX version does indeed appear to faster than the SSE version, both for the original implementations and the optimised implementations. The optimised implementations are significantly faster than the original versions, however, by an even greater margin.

I can only guess that either your compiler is not generating very good code for AVX (or maybe you forgot to enable compiler optimisations ?), or perhaps there is something suspect about your benchmarking method.

Comment: It's really weird, I'll check and post my results - if any

Comment: With your code I understood what you meant by "moving the hadd out of the loop". I thought you wanted to somehow only multiply first (without the last add) and the magically sum them up. THANKS!

Comment: Yes, as a rule of thumb horizontal operations should generally be avoided in SIMD code, and when they can't be avoided they should ideally be outside any performance-critical loops.

Comment: I am compiling with VS2012, "-O3" and "/arch:AVX". Could that be an issue?

Comment: I would have thought that either /O2 or /Ox would be fine with Visual Studio, but I don't really do much work on Windows and I'm not sure how good Visual Studio is when it comes to AVX code generation. gcc, clang and Intel's ICC all generate pretty good AVX code, so you might want to consider trying a different compiler. You might also want to review your benchmarking methods, as there are many pitfalls for the unwary. If you can get my test harness above to compile with Visual Studio then it would be interesting to see what numbers you get for the timing.

Comment: Those are my speedups: sse_fast/sse: 2.8  //  avx_fast/avx: 3.8  //  avx/sse: 1.3  //  avx_fast/sse_fast: 1.7. That's almost what @PaulR: has repoted. The horizontal add seems to be *very* expensive

Comment: OK - thanks - that seems to be consistent with my numbers then ?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your help. I still need to figure out where the loss in speed comes from in my original code

Comment: changing /ach:SSE to /arch:AVX makes a*huge* difference (SSE speeds are the same, AVX improves by a factor of more than 10)

Comment: Note that in my code all the caches are pre-warmed, and I use quite a large number of repeats. Note also that I take steps to prevent the compiler from being too clever and optimising away loops/function calls etc.

Comment: "all the caches are pre-warmed": that's the case since the arrays are initialized just before usage, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `/arch:` switches do but evidently they make a big difference for you!

Comment: What I usually do is call each function of interest once first (and typically use the output for validation) before I start timing - that way both the data caches and the instruction cache are warmed, and all the relevant code is paged in, so no page faults or avoidable cache misses in the timing loops.

Comment: The factor of 10 is almost certainly from mixing VEX with non-VEX-encoded SSE instructions, without using `VZEROUPPER` in between.  Using `/arch:AVX` probably means all simd instructions in the whole program are emitted in VEX encoding, avoiding the problem.  `/arch:SSE` I assume results in VEX-encoding only when necessary. (e.g. `_mm256` intrinsics.)  Also, if you try to make an FMA version of this, you might need to unroll by 2 and get a 2nd set of accumulators going.  FMA will increase the loop-carried dep chain to 5 cycles (for FMA) from 3 (`addps`).

Comment: @PeterCordes: that makes sense - I'd always assumed that unless you're writing assembler you couldn't run into problems with VEX v non-VEX instructions - either your compiler is generating AVX + VEX SSE instructions or it's just generating plain (non VEX) SSE. I think that's the case with gcc/clang/ICC, at least in my experience, but it sounds like it might not always be true for MSVC (depending on /ARCH setting) ?